# Solve an integral equation in an Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $V_n\subseteq [H(div;\Omega)]^{2\times 2}$ and $Q_n\subseteq [L^2(\Omega)]^2$ two finte dimentional spaces such that $div(H_n)\subseteq Q_n$. Suppose that $u\in Q_n$ is well known. I must solve this equation for $\mathbf{v}\in V_n$:

$(\mathbf{v},\chi)_{0,\Omega}+(div(\chi),u)_{0,\Omega}=0 \,\,\,\,\forall \chi\in V_n$

where $(\cdot,\cdot)_{0,\Omega}$ is the $L^2$ scalar product. Note that the first scalar product is tensorial and the second is vectorial.

I consider a basis of $H_n$ but i can't prove that the matrix asociated isn't singular. Any ideas? thanks for your help